# Print iframe contents jquery not working in remote server

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to do a print operation in a html report page. I only want some portion of the html page as PDF print in 'Export PDF' button click.
So I placed the required content to a new iframe and print the iframe on button click. And its working PERFECT.

Here is my code

```js
$('#btnprint').on('click',function(){
      $('#print-iframe').contents().find('html').html($('#divprintheader').html() + $('#divreport').html());

    $("#print-iframe").get(0).contentWindow.print();
});
```

```html
<table id="tblentrancereport" class="reporttable" style="width: 100%">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Count</th>
                                    <th>Amount</th>
                                </tr>

                                </thead>
                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
 <div id="divprintheader" style="display: none">

                    From : <span id="spnfromdate"></span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; To : <span id="spntodate"></span>
                    <div id="divprintfilter">
                        Filtered By : <span id="spnfilteredby"></span>
                        <div id="divcontentbelongto">

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

<button id="btnprint">Export PDF</button>
                <iframe name="print_frame" id="print-iframe" width="0" height="0" frameborder="0" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Unfortunately when i moved the code to my production server (windows server 2012), I am not getting the contents in iframe(print window is coming). Though iframe is populated with new dynamic formed content(i can see when inspecting page element) its not showing in the print. Can anyone figure out where I got mistaken.

Here are the screenshots

[image: Image 1]The print when i tried in my localhost

[image: Image 2]The print when i tried in my server

**UPDATE**
And the strange thing is,when I inspect the elements and expand contents in developer tool and then click on 'Export PDF' button, its working.. :O

Cannot trace out the error :(

Comment: Maybe try and remove the `src` attribute with  `sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts"`

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz Thanks for reply! But not working.. :(

Comment: And the strange thing is,when I inspect the elements and expand contents in developer tool and then click on 'Export PDF' button, its working.

Cannot trace out the error :(

Comment: Maybe `window.frames.pdfFrame.print()`?  If not checkout - http://www.sitepoint.com/load-pdf-iframe-call-print/

Comment: Still the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ClickHereToPrint(){
    try{ 
        var oIframe = document.getElementById('ifrmPrint');
        var oContent = document.getElementById('divToPrint').innerHTML;
        var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
        if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
  oDoc.write("<html><head><title>title</title>");
  oDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
  oDoc.write(oContent + "</body></html>");     
  oDoc.close();      
    }
    catch(e){
     self.print();
    }
}
</script>
</head>


<body>

<a onclick="ClickHereToPrint();">Print</a>

 <iframe id='ifrmPrint' src='#' style="width:0px; height:0px;"></iframe>
 <div id="divToPrint">
  content
 </div>
</body>
```

Though I couldn't figure out the issue, this solution works perfect. Thanks !!